# Shopware - disable PHP less compiler?

Tags: svg, less, shopware, lessphp

Shopware version 5.2.x

I use gulp and its browsersync plugin to compile my less files for quicker development.

I have a strange problem - some entries of SVGs defined in the less file are compiled with gulp-less seamlessly, but when I reload the page, the built-in php LESS compiler of Shopware seems to encounter an error for some longer SVG definitions.

For example:

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 608 400'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23F49B00' d='M360.6 169.5c-26.6 20-65.3 30.2-99.2 30.2-46.6 0-88.9-17.5-121-46-2.4-2.4 0-5.4 2.4-3.6 34.5 20 76.8 32.1 121 32.1 29.6 0 62.3-6 91.9-18.7 5.5-1.9 9.1 2.9 4.9 6'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23F49B00' d='M371.4 156.8c-3.6-4.2-22.4-1.8-31.5-1.2-2.4.6-3-1.8-.6-3.6 15.1-10.9 40.5-7.9 43.5-4.2 3 3.6-.6 29-15.1 40.5-2.4 1.8-4.2.6-3.6-1.8 3.7-6.8 11-24.9 7.3-29.7'/%3E%3Cpath d='M340.6 76.3V66c0-1.8 1.2-2.4 2.4-2.4h46.6c1.2 0 2.4 1.2 2.4 2.4v9.1c0 1.2-1.2 3.6-3.6 6.7l-24.2 34.5c9.1 0 18.8 1.2 26.6 6 1.8 1.2 2.4 2.4 2.4 4.2v10.9c0 1.8-1.8 3-3.6 2.4-14.5-7.3-33.3-8.5-49.6 0-1.8.6-3-.6-3-2.4v-10.9c0-1.8 0-4.8 1.8-7.3l27.8-40.5h-24.2c-.6 0-1.8-.6-1.8-2.4M170 141.6h-14.5c-1.2 0-2.4-1.2-2.4-2.4V66c0-1.2 1.2-2.4 3-2.4h13.3c1.2 0 2.4 1.2 2.4 2.4v9.7c3.6-9.1 9.7-13.3 18.8-13.3s14.5 4.2 18.8 13.3c3.6-9.1 11.5-13.3 20-13.3 6 0 12.7 2.4 16.3 7.9 4.2 6 3.6 15.1 3.6 23v46c0 1.2-1.2 2.4-3 2.4h-14.5c-1.2 0-2.4-1.2-2.4-2.4v-38.7c0-3 0-10.9-.6-13.9-1.2-4.8-4.2-6-8.5-6-3.6 0-7.3 2.4-8.5 6-1.2 3.6-1.2 9.7-1.2 13.9v38.7c0 1.2-1.2 2.4-3 2.4h-13.3c-1.2 0-2.4-1.2-2.4-2.4v-38.7c0-7.9 1.2-20-9.1-20-10.3 0-9.7 11.5-9.7 20v38.7c0 1.1-1.3 2.3-3.1 2.3M433.1 61.8c21.2 0 32.7 18.1 32.7 41.1 0 22.4-12.7 39.9-32.7 39.9-20.6 0-32.1-18.1-32.1-40.5.1-22.4 11.6-40.5 32.1-40.5m0 15.1c-10.3 0-10.9 14.5-10.9 23 0 9.1 0 27.8 10.9 27.8s11.5-15.1 11.5-24.8c0-6 0-13.3-2.4-19.4-1.2-4.8-4.2-6.6-9.1-6.6M493 141.6h-14.5c-1.2 0-2.4-1.2-2.4-2.4V66c0-1.2 1.2-2.4 2.4-2.4h13.3c1.2 0 2.4 1.2 2.4 1.8v10.9c4.2-10.3 9.7-14.5 19.4-14.5 6.7 0 12.7 2.4 16.3 8.5 3.6 6 3.6 15.7 3.6 23v46c0 1.2-1.2 2.4-3 2.4H516c-1.2 0-2.4-1.2-2.4-2.4V99.9c0-7.9 1.2-20-9.1-20-3.6 0-6.7 2.4-8.5 6-1.8 4.2-2.4 9.1-2.4 13.9v39.3c2.4 1.3 1.2 2.5-.6 2.5M327.3 128.9c-2.4-3.6-5.4-6.7-5.4-13.3V93.2c0-9.7.6-18.1-6-24.8-5.4-5.4-14.5-7.3-21.2-7.3-13.9 0-29 4.8-32.1 21.8 0 1.8 1.2 3 2.4 3l13.9 1.2c1.2 0 2.4-1.2 2.4-2.4 1.2-5.4 6-8.5 11.5-8.5 3 0 6 1.2 7.9 3.6 1.8 3 1.8 6.7 1.8 10.3V92c-7.9.6-18.8 1.2-26.6 4.8-9.1 4.2-15.1 12.1-15.1 23.6 0 15.1 9.1 22.4 21.2 22.4 10.3 0 15.7-2.4 23.6-10.3 3 4.2 3.6 5.4 8.5 9.7 1.2.6 2.4 0 3.6-.6 3-2.4 8.5-7.3 9.7-9.1 1.1-.5 1.1-2.4-.1-3.6zm-23-22.3h-.6c0 5.4 0 10.3-2.4 15.1-2.4 4.2-6 6.7-9.7 6.7-5.4 0-8.5-4.2-8.5-10.3 0-12.1 10.9-14.5 21.2-14.5v3zM142.2 128.9c-2.4-3.6-5.4-6.7-5.4-13.3V93.2c0-9.7.6-18.1-6-24.8-6-5.4-15.1-7.3-21.8-7.3C95 61.2 79.9 66 76.9 83c0 1.8 1.2 3 2.4 3l13.9 1.2c1.2 0 2.4-1.2 2.4-2.4 1.2-5.4 6-8.5 11.5-8.5 3 0 6 1.2 7.9 3.6 1.8 3 1.8 6.7 1.8 10.3V92c-8.5 1.2-19.4 1.8-26.6 4.2-9.1 4.2-15.1 12.1-15.1 23.6 0 15.1 9.1 22.4 21.2 22.4 10.3 0 15.7-2.4 23.6-10.3 2.4 4.2 3 5.4 7.9 9.7 1.2.6 2.4.6 3.6 0 2.4-2.4 7.9-7.3 10.9-9.1 1.1-.5.5-2.4-.1-3.6zm-24.8-22.3h-.6c0 5.4 0 10.3-2.4 15.1-2.4 4.2-6 6.7-9.7 6.7-5.4 0-8.5-4.2-8.5-10.3 0-12.1 10.9-14.5 21.2-14.5v3z'/%3E%3Cg fill='%23F49B00'%3E%3Cpath d='M63 230.5c-7.3 0-14.5 1.2-21.8 4.2-.6 0-1.2.6-1.2 1.2v101c0 .6.6 1.8 1.8 1.8h7.9c.6 0 1.8-.6 1.8-1.8v-33.3c3 1.2 7.3 1.8 10.9 1.8 21.2 0 35.7-15.7 35.7-38.1 0-22.8-13.3-36.8-35.1-36.8m-.6 64.8c-4.2 0-7.3-.6-11.5-2.4v-50.2c3.6-1.2 7.3-1.8 11.5-1.8 15.1 0 24.2 10.3 24.2 26.6.6 17.5-9.1 27.8-24.2 27.8M157.9 276.5v-21.8c0-15.1-9.1-24.2-24.8-24.2-6 0-14.5 1.2-23.6 7.3-.6.6-1.2 1.2-.6 1.8l3.6 6c0 .6.6.6 1.2.6h1.2c4.8-3 10.3-5.4 18.8-5.4 9.1 0 13.9 5.4 13.9 15.1v3.6l-12.1.6c-7.3 0-12.7 1.2-17.5 3-7.9 3.6-12.7 10.9-12.7 20 0 13.3 9.7 22.4 23 22.4 7.3 0 13.9-3 20-8.5l1.2 5.4c0 .6.6 1.2 1.8 1.2h6.7c.6 0 1.2 0 1.2-.6.6-.6.6-.6 0-1.2-.7-3.5-1.3-11.4-1.3-25.3m-10.8-6.6v16.3c-4.2 4.2-10.3 9.7-18.7 9.7-7.3 0-12.1-4.8-12.1-12.7 0-4.2 1.8-7.9 6-10.3 3.6-1.8 7.3-2.4 13.3-3h11.5zM225.1 232.4h-8.5c-.6 0-1.2.6-1.8 1.2l-17.5 55-23.6-55c0-.6-.6-1.2-1.2-1.2H164c-.6 0-1.2 0-1.2.6s-.6 1.2 0 1.2l30.2 68.9c-4.8 16.9-11.5 24.8-21.2 24.8-3 0-6-.6-8.5-1.8h-1.2c-.6 0-.6.6-.6 1.2l-1.8 6.7c0 .6 0 1.8 1.2 1.8 3.6 1.2 6.7 1.8 11.5 1.8 10.9 0 21.8-3.6 30.2-29L228 233v-1.2c-1.7.6-2.3.6-2.9.6M311 230.5c-7.9 0-16.3 3.6-25.4 11.5-3.6-7.3-9.7-11.5-18.1-11.5-7.9 0-15.1 3-23 9.7l-.6-6.7c0-.6-.6-1.2-1.8-1.2h-6.7c-.6 0-1.8.6-1.8 1.8V303c0 .6.6 1.8 1.8 1.8h7.9c.6 0 1.8-.6 1.8-1.8v-50.8c6.7-5.4 13.3-10.9 21.2-10.9 7.9 0 10.9 5.4 10.9 18.1v44.2c0 .6.6 1.8 1.8 1.8h7.9c.6 0 1.8-.6 1.8-1.8V257v-4.2c6-5.4 13.3-10.9 21.2-10.9 7.9 0 10.9 5.4 10.9 18.1v44.2c0 .6.6 1.8 1.8 1.8h7.9c1.2 0 1.8-.6 1.8-1.8v-46.6c-.2-20.4-11.1-27.1-21.3-27.1M371.4 230.5c-16.9 0-28.4 15.1-28.4 36.3 0 23.6 12.7 38.7 32.7 38.7 7.3 0 16.3-2.4 21.8-6 .6-.6.6-1.2.6-1.8l-2.4-5.4c0-.6-.6-.6-1.2-.6h-1.2c-3.6 1.8-9.1 4.2-15.7 4.2-15.7 0-22.4-13.3-23-24.8h43.5c.6 0 1.8-.6 1.8-1.8v-1.8c-1.2-23-11.5-37-28.5-37m-16.9 30.3c.6-12.1 7.9-20 16.9-20 10.3 0 15.1 9.7 15.7 20h-32.6zM444.6 230.5c-7.3 0-15.1 3-23 9.7l-.6-6.7c0-.6-.6-1.2-1.8-1.2h-6.7c-.6 0-1.8.6-1.8 1.8V303c0 .6.6 1.8 1.8 1.8h7.9c.6 0 1.8-.6 1.8-1.8v-50.8c6.7-5.4 13.3-10.9 21.2-10.9 4.8 0 11.5 1.8 11.5 18.1v44.2c0 .6.6 1.8 1.8 1.8h7.9c.6 0 1.8-.6 1.8-1.8V257c-.6-19.8-11.5-26.5-21.8-26.5M515.4 291.6c0-.6-.6-.6-1.2-.6H513c-3 1.8-7.3 4.2-10.9 4.2-2.4 0-5.4-.6-5.4-7.3v-46.6H513c.6 0 1.2-.6 1.2-1.2l2.4-6.7v-1.2c-.6-.6-.6-.6-1.2-.6h-18.7v-16.3c0-.6 0-1.2-.6-1.2-.6-.6-1.2-.6-1.2 0l-7.9 3c-.6 0-1.2.6-1.2 1.8V233h-9.7c-.6 0-1.8.6-1.8 1.8v6.7c0 .6.6 1.8 1.8 1.8h9.7v47.2c0 10.9 5.4 16.3 15.1 16.3 6.7 0 13.3-3.6 16.9-6.7.6-.6.6-1.2.6-1.8l-3-6.7zM551.1 262.6l-.6-.6c-7.9-3.6-13.3-6.6-13.3-12.7 0-6 4.2-9.1 13.3-9.1 6.7 0 10.9 1.8 14.5 3.6h1.2c.6 0 .6-.6.6-1.2v-7.3c0-.6-.6-1.2-1.2-1.2-3.6-1.8-9.7-3-16.3-3-16.3 0-23.6 9.7-23.6 20 0 13.3 9.7 17.5 17.5 21.2l1.2.6c7.3 3 12.7 6 12.7 12.7 0 9.7-9.7 10.9-14.5 10.9-7.9 0-12.7-3-15.7-4.8h-1.2c-.6 0-.6.6-1.2.6l-2.4 6c0 .6 0 1.2.6 1.8 3 2.4 10.3 6 19.4 6 15.7 0 26-8.5 26-21.2 0-5.4-1.8-10.3-4.8-13.3-2.6-4.2-7.4-6.6-12.2-9'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Why gulp-less compiles the above, but php-less fails is beyond my understanding and maybe someone has a better way of resolving this?

I do not eventually, want to allow the php LESS compiler to compile my less files again (at least on my development environment). I believe, this is also a temporary solution to my problem.

Anyone could tell me how to disable the built in less compiler please?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. In CSS you should include the `.svg` as a File, not the Source Code.

Put your `.svg` Image inside the `img` Directory of your Theme and then load the Image in the Background e.g

```
.my--background {
   background:url(../../img/myimage.svg);
}
```

You may also read a bit more about `.svg` Images on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-4)

Comment: I am interested to know more from you on this, since you said I'm doing it wrong. I am using the SVG included in the css declaration because I want to reduce the number of http requests. Also, I have other SVG which are working fine the same way; just the real long ones have a problem.